# Query IIf Formula

Tags: ms-access

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJUAP.png)

Formula in query

```
CheckTSX: [XPostdrillTS]-[XPlan]
CheckTSY: [Y PostdrillTS]-[YPlan]

CheckGPSX : [XPostdrillGPS]-[XPlan]
CheckGPSY: [YPostdrillGPS]-[YPlan]

CheckTS: IIf([Spasi]=25 And [CheckTSX]<=2,5 Or [CheckTSY]<=2,5;"Correct";IIf([Spasi]=50 And [CheckTSX]<=5 Or [CheckTSY]<=5;"Correct";IIf([Spasi]=100 And [CheckTSX]<=10 Or [CheckTSY]<=10;"Correct";IIf([Spasi]=200 And [CheckTSX]<=20 Or [CheckTSY]<=20;"Correct";"Incorrect"))))
```

I want to display the correct value or not from the formula, where in certain spaces there are certain criteria for the results of subtracting values from the existing X and Y value categories. The output of the formula is "Correct" or "Incorrect". Is there something wrong with the formula? Thank You. Ask for corrections from all friends ?

I wish my query formula can run correctly

Comment: Is the result not what you expect? Sample data and desired output should be provided as formatted text table, not image.

Comment: You are mixing AND and OR operators. Use ( ) to control order of calculation. `A AND B OR C` is not the same as `A AND (B OR C)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
CheckTS: IIf([Spasi]=25 And ([CheckTSX]<=2,5 Or [CheckTSY]<=2,5);"Correct";IIf([Spasi]=50 And ([CheckTSX]<=5 Or [CheckTSY]<=5);"Correct";IIf([Spasi]=100 And ([CheckTSX]<=10 Or [CheckTSY]<=10);"Correct";IIf([Spasi]=200 And ([CheckTSX]<=20 Or [CheckTSY]<=20);"Correct";"Incorrect"))))
```

or:

```
CheckTS: IIf([Spasi] In (25, 50, 100, 200) And ([CheckTSX]<=[Spasi]/10 Or [CheckTSY]<=[Spasi]/10);"Correct";"Incorrect")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the formula do not work correctly. Maybe the formula must repair again

Comment: I already post my new question still in IFF Formula. Hope this post can make you understand. Thank you